# Android - NullPointerException SimpleAdapter - Pinned section ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

I created a `ListView` with `pinned` which works well once. But when I arrive latest item of `ListView` crashes on me and says `NullPointerException`.

I need that when I arrive latest item get next 5 of items .

`MainActivity.java` :

```
public class PinnedSectionListActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
    public static Context context;
    public static Context _context;
    public static SQLiteDatabase sql;
    public  Cursor cursor;
    public  Cursor cursorA;
    public boolean flag = false;
    public  Integer count = 0;
    public  List<Items> result;
    public  List<ItemsT> resultT;

    static class SimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> implements PinnedSectionListView.PinnedSectionListAdapter {
        private List<Items> Results;
        private List<ItemsT> ResultsT;
        private Integer counts;
        private static final int[] COLORS = new int[] {
                R.color.green_light, R.color.orange_light,
                R.color.blue_light, R.color.red_light };

        public SimpleAdapter(Context context,List<Items> MResults,List<ItemsT> MresultT,Integer count , int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
            this.Results = MResults;
            this.ResultsT = MresultT;
            this.counts = count;
            generateDataset(false);
        }
        public void generateDataset(boolean clear) {
            int y = 0;
            if (clear) clear();
            prepareSections(counts);
            int sectionPosition = 0, listPosition = 0;
            for (char i=0; i<counts; i++) {
                final Items ci = Results.get(i);
                Item section = new Item(Item.SECTION, ci.WTitleO);
                section.sectionPosition = sectionPosition;
                section.listPosition = listPosition++;
                onSectionAdded(section, sectionPosition);
                add(section);

                for (int j=0;j<ci.count;j++) {
                    final ItemsT xx = ResultsT.get(y);
                    Item item = new Item(Item.ITEM, xx.WTitleT);
                    item.sectionPosition = sectionPosition;
                    item.listPosition = listPosition++;
                    y++;
                    add(item);
                }
                sectionPosition++;
            }
        }
        protected void prepareSections(int sectionsNumber) { }
        protected void onSectionAdded(Item section, int sectionPosition) { }

        @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            view.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            view.setTag("" + position);
            Item item = getItem(position);
            if (item.type == Item.SECTION) {

                view.setBackgroundColor(parent.getResources().getColor(COLORS[item.sectionPosition % COLORS.length]));
            }
            return view;
        }

        @Override public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return getItem(position).type;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isItemViewTypePinned(int viewType) {
            return viewType == Item.SECTION;
        }

    }

    static class Items {
        public int conO ;
        public String WTitleO;
        public int count;
    }

    static class ItemsT {
        public String WTitleT;
    }

    static class Item {

        public static final int ITEM = 0;
        public static final int SECTION = 1;

        public final int type;
        public final String text;

        public int sectionPosition;
        public int listPosition;

        public Item(int type, String text) {
            this.type = type;
            this.text = text;
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            return text;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        _context = this;

        DB db = new DB(context);
        db.CreateFile();
        try {
            db.CreateandOpenDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sql = db.openDataBase();

        test();
    }

    public void test(){
        result = new ArrayList<Items>();
        resultT = new ArrayList<ItemsT>();
        try {
            cursor = sql.rawQuery("SELECT (select count() as number from WebSite_BookPageDB22 as b where b.ParentID = a.ContentID) as count" +
                    " ,ContentID,Title" +
                    " FROM WebSite_BookPageDB22 as a" +
                    " WHERE ArticleID = '" + 61799 + "' AND ParentID = '" + 0 + "'order by PageID ASC LIMIT 5", null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        Items ci = new Items();
                        ci.conO = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ContentID"));
                        ci.WTitleO = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Title"));
                        ci.count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("count"));
                        if(flag == false) {
                            count = cursor.getCount();
                            flag = true;
                        }
                        cursorA = sql.rawQuery("select Title from WebSite_BookPageDB22 where ParentID = '" + ci.conO +"' order by PageID ASC", null);
                        try {
                            if (cursorA != null && cursorA.moveToFirst()) {
                                do {
                                    ItemsT cty = new ItemsT();
                                    cty.WTitleT = cursorA.getString(cursorA.getColumnIndex("Title"));
                                    resultT.add(cty);
                                } while (cursorA.moveToNext());
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            Log.i("xxx", "You have an error");
                        }finally {
                            if (cursorA != null) {
                                cursorA.close();
                            }
                        }
                        result.add(ci);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

        SimpleAdapter adapt = new SimpleAdapter(_context, result, resultT, count, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1);
        setListAdapter(adapt);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Item item = (Item) getListView().getAdapter().getItem(position);
        if (item != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item " + position + ": " + item.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item: " + v.getTag() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

And `PinnedSectionListView.java` :

```
public class PinnedSectionListView extends ListView {

    //-- inner classes

    /** List adapter to be implemented for being used with PinnedSectionListView adapter. */
    public static interface PinnedSectionListAdapter extends ListAdapter {
        /** This method shall return 'true' if views of given type has to be pinned. */
        boolean isItemViewTypePinned(int viewType);
    }

    /** Wrapper class for pinned section view and its position in the list. */
    static class PinnedSection {
        public View view;
        public int position;
        public long id;
    }

    //-- class fields

    // fields used for handling touch events
    private final Rect mTouchRect = new Rect();
    private final PointF mTouchPoint = new PointF();
    private int mTouchSlop;
    private View mTouchTarget;
    private MotionEvent mDownEvent;

    // fields used for drawing shadow under a pinned section
    private GradientDrawable mShadowDrawable;
    private int mSectionsDistanceY;
    private int mShadowHeight;

    /** Delegating listener, can be null. */
    OnScrollListener mDelegateOnScrollListener;

    /** Shadow for being recycled, can be null. */
    PinnedSection mRecycleSection;

    /** shadow instance with a pinned view, can be null. */
    PinnedSection mPinnedSection;

    /** Pinned view Y-translation. We use it to stick pinned view to the next section. */
    int mTranslateY;

    /** Scroll listener which does the magic */
    private final OnScrollListener mOnScrollListener = new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (mDelegateOnScrollListener != null) { // delegate
                mDelegateOnScrollListener.onScrollStateChanged(view, scrollState);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if (mDelegateOnScrollListener != null) { // delegate
                mDelegateOnScrollListener.onScroll(view, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
            }
            if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
            {
                PinnedSectionListActivity xx = new PinnedSectionListActivity();
                xx.flag = false;
                xx.test();
                /*Intent refresh = new Intent(PinnedSectionListActivity._context, PinnedSectionListActivity.class);
                PinnedSectionListActivity._context.startActivity(refresh);*/
            }

            // get expected adapter or fail fast
            ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
            if (adapter == null || visibleItemCount == 0) return; // nothing to do

            final boolean isFirstVisibleItemSection =
                    isItemViewTypePinned(adapter, adapter.getItemViewType(firstVisibleItem));

            if (isFirstVisibleItemSection) {
                View sectionView = getChildAt(0);
                if (sectionView.getTop() == getPaddingTop()) { // view sticks to the top, no need for pinned shadow
                    destroyPinnedShadow();
                } else { // section doesn't stick to the top, make sure we have a pinned shadow
                    ensureShadowForPosition(firstVisibleItem, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount);
                }

            } else { // section is not at the first visible position
                int sectionPosition = findCurrentSectionPosition(firstVisibleItem);
                if (sectionPosition > -1) { // we have section position
                    ensureShadowForPosition(sectionPosition, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount);
                } else { // there is no section for the first visible item, destroy shadow
                    destroyPinnedShadow();
                }
            }
        };

    };

    /** Default change observer. */
    private final DataSetObserver mDataSetObserver = new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override public void onChanged() {
            recreatePinnedShadow();
        };
        @Override public void onInvalidated() {
            recreatePinnedShadow();
        }
    };

    //-- constructors

    public PinnedSectionListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
    }

    public PinnedSectionListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        setOnScrollListener(mOnScrollListener);
        mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext()).getScaledTouchSlop();
        initShadow(true);
    }

    //-- public API methods

    public void setShadowVisible(boolean visible) {
        initShadow(visible);
        if (mPinnedSection != null) {
            View v = mPinnedSection.view;
            invalidate(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom() + mShadowHeight);
        }
    }

    //-- pinned section drawing methods

    public void initShadow(boolean visible) {
        if (visible) {
            if (mShadowDrawable == null) {
                mShadowDrawable = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                        new int[] { Color.parseColor("#ffa0a0a0"), Color.parseColor("#50a0a0a0"), Color.parseColor("#00a0a0a0")});
                mShadowHeight = (int) (8 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            }
        } else {
            if (mShadowDrawable != null) {
                mShadowDrawable = null;
                mShadowHeight = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /** Create shadow wrapper with a pinned view for a view at given position */
    void createPinnedShadow(int position) {

        // try to recycle shadow
        PinnedSection pinnedShadow = mRecycleSection;
        mRecycleSection = null;

        // create new shadow, if needed
        if (pinnedShadow == null) pinnedShadow = new PinnedSection();
        // request new view using recycled view, if such
        View pinnedView = getAdapter().getView(position, pinnedShadow.view, PinnedSectionListView.this);

        // read layout parameters
        LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) pinnedView.getLayoutParams();
        if (layoutParams == null) {
            layoutParams = (LayoutParams) generateDefaultLayoutParams();
            pinnedView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }

        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(layoutParams.height);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(layoutParams.height);

        if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) heightMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;

        int maxHeight = getHeight() - getListPaddingTop() - getListPaddingBottom();
        if (heightSize > maxHeight) heightSize = maxHeight;

        // measure & layout
        int ws = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth() - getListPaddingLeft() - getListPaddingRight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int hs = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(heightSize, heightMode);
        pinnedView.measure(ws, hs);
        pinnedView.layout(0, 0, pinnedView.getMeasuredWidth(), pinnedView.getMeasuredHeight());
        mTranslateY = 0;

        // initialize pinned shadow
        pinnedShadow.view = pinnedView;
        pinnedShadow.position = position;
        pinnedShadow.id = getAdapter().getItemId(position);

        // store pinned shadow
        mPinnedSection = pinnedShadow;
    }

    /** Destroy shadow wrapper for currently pinned view */
    void destroyPinnedShadow() {
        if (mPinnedSection != null) {
            // keep shadow for being recycled later
            mRecycleSection = mPinnedSection;
            mPinnedSection = null;
        }
    }

    /** Makes sure we have an actual pinned shadow for given position. */
    void ensureShadowForPosition(int sectionPosition, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount) {
        if (visibleItemCount < 2) { // no need for creating shadow at all, we have a single visible item
            destroyPinnedShadow();
            return;
        }

        if (mPinnedSection != null
                && mPinnedSection.position != sectionPosition) { // invalidate shadow, if required
            destroyPinnedShadow();
        }

        if (mPinnedSection == null) { // create shadow, if empty
            createPinnedShadow(sectionPosition);
        }

        // align shadow according to next section position, if needed
        int nextPosition = sectionPosition + 1;
        if (nextPosition < getCount()) {
            int nextSectionPosition = findFirstVisibleSectionPosition(nextPosition,
                    visibleItemCount - (nextPosition - firstVisibleItem));
            if (nextSectionPosition > -1) {
                View nextSectionView = getChildAt(nextSectionPosition - firstVisibleItem);
                final int bottom = mPinnedSection.view.getBottom() + getPaddingTop();
                mSectionsDistanceY = nextSectionView.getTop() - bottom;
                if (mSectionsDistanceY < 0) {
                    // next section overlaps pinned shadow, move it up
                    mTranslateY = mSectionsDistanceY;
                } else {
                    // next section does not overlap with pinned, stick to top
                    mTranslateY = 0;
                }
            } else {
                // no other sections are visible, stick to top
                mTranslateY = 0;
                mSectionsDistanceY = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
        }

    }

    int findFirstVisibleSectionPosition(int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount) {
        ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();

        int adapterDataCount = adapter.getCount();
        if (getLastVisiblePosition() >= adapterDataCount) return -1; // dataset has changed, no candidate

        if (firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount >= adapterDataCount){//added to prevent index Outofbound (in case)
            visibleItemCount = adapterDataCount-firstVisibleItem;
        }

        for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < visibleItemCount; childIndex++) {
            int position = firstVisibleItem + childIndex;
            int viewType = adapter.getItemViewType(position);
            if (isItemViewTypePinned(adapter, viewType)) return position;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    int findCurrentSectionPosition(int fromPosition) {
        ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();

        if (fromPosition >= adapter.getCount()) return -1; // dataset has changed, no candidate

        if (adapter instanceof SectionIndexer) {
            // try fast way by asking section indexer
            SectionIndexer indexer = (SectionIndexer) adapter;
            int sectionPosition = indexer.getSectionForPosition(fromPosition);
            int itemPosition = indexer.getPositionForSection(sectionPosition);
            int typeView = adapter.getItemViewType(itemPosition);
            if (isItemViewTypePinned(adapter, typeView)) {
                return itemPosition;
            } // else, no luck
        }

        // try slow way by looking through to the next section item above
        for (int position=fromPosition; position>=0; position--) {
            int viewType = adapter.getItemViewType(position);
            if (isItemViewTypePinned(adapter, viewType)) return position;
        }
        return -1; // no candidate found
    }

    void recreatePinnedShadow() {
        destroyPinnedShadow();
        ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
        if (adapter != null && adapter.getCount() > 0) {
            int firstVisiblePosition = getFirstVisiblePosition();
            int sectionPosition = findCurrentSectionPosition(firstVisiblePosition);
            if (sectionPosition == -1) return; // no views to pin, exit
            ensureShadowForPosition(sectionPosition,
                    firstVisiblePosition, getLastVisiblePosition() - firstVisiblePosition);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener listener) {
        if (listener == mOnScrollListener) {
            super.setOnScrollListener(listener);
        } else {
            mDelegateOnScrollListener = listener;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        post(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() { // restore pinned view after configuration change
                recreatePinnedShadow();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {

        // assert adapter in debug mode
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && adapter != null) {
            if (!(adapter instanceof PinnedSectionListAdapter))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Does your adapter implement PinnedSectionListAdapter?");
            if (adapter.getViewTypeCount() < 2)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Does your adapter handle at least two types" +
                        " of views in getViewTypeCount() method: items and sections?");
        }

        // unregister observer at old adapter and register on new one
        ListAdapter oldAdapter = getAdapter();
        if (oldAdapter != null) oldAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        if (adapter != null) adapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);

        // destroy pinned shadow, if new adapter is not same as old one
        if (oldAdapter != adapter) destroyPinnedShadow();

        super.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        if (mPinnedSection != null) {
            int parentWidth = r - l - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
            int shadowWidth = mPinnedSection.view.getWidth();
            if (parentWidth != shadowWidth) {
                recreatePinnedShadow();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        if (mPinnedSection != null) {

            // prepare variables
            int pLeft = getListPaddingLeft();
            int pTop = getListPaddingTop();
            View view = mPinnedSection.view;

            // draw child
            canvas.save();

            int clipHeight = view.getHeight() +
                    (mShadowDrawable == null ? 0 : Math.min(mShadowHeight, mSectionsDistanceY));
            canvas.clipRect(pLeft, pTop, pLeft + view.getWidth(), pTop + clipHeight);

            canvas.translate(pLeft, pTop + mTranslateY);
            drawChild(canvas, mPinnedSection.view, getDrawingTime());

            if (mShadowDrawable != null && mSectionsDistanceY > 0) {
                mShadowDrawable.setBounds(mPinnedSection.view.getLeft(),
                        mPinnedSection.view.getBottom(),
                        mPinnedSection.view.getRight(),
                        mPinnedSection.view.getBottom() + mShadowHeight);
                mShadowDrawable.draw(canvas);
            }

            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

    //-- touch handling methods

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();
        final int action = ev.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                && mTouchTarget == null
                && mPinnedSection != null
                && isPinnedViewTouched(mPinnedSection.view, x, y)) { // create touch target

            // user touched pinned view
            mTouchTarget = mPinnedSection.view;
            mTouchPoint.x = x;
            mTouchPoint.y = y;

            // copy down event for eventually be used later
            mDownEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
        }

        if (mTouchTarget != null) {
            if (isPinnedViewTouched(mTouchTarget, x, y)) { // forward event to pinned view
                mTouchTarget.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            }

            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) { // perform onClick on pinned view
                super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
                performPinnedItemClick();
                clearTouchTarget();

            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) { // cancel
                clearTouchTarget();

            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                if (Math.abs(y - mTouchPoint.y) > mTouchSlop) {

                    // cancel sequence on touch target
                    MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
                    event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                    mTouchTarget.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                    event.recycle();

                    // provide correct sequence to super class for further handling
                    super.dispatchTouchEvent(mDownEvent);
                    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
                    clearTouchTarget();

                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        // call super if this was not our pinned view
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private boolean isPinnedViewTouched(View view, float x, float y) {
        view.getHitRect(mTouchRect);

        // by taping top or bottom padding, the list performs on click on a border item.
        // we don't add top padding here to keep behavior consistent.
        mTouchRect.top += mTranslateY;

        mTouchRect.bottom += mTranslateY + getPaddingTop();
        mTouchRect.left += getPaddingLeft();
        mTouchRect.right -= getPaddingRight();
        return mTouchRect.contains((int)x, (int)y);
    }

    private void clearTouchTarget() {
        mTouchTarget = null;
        if (mDownEvent != null) {
            mDownEvent.recycle();
            mDownEvent = null;
        }
    }

    private boolean performPinnedItemClick() {
        if (mPinnedSection == null) return false;

        OnItemClickListener listener = getOnItemClickListener();
        if (listener != null && getAdapter().isEnabled(mPinnedSection.position)) {
            View view =  mPinnedSection.view;
            playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
            if (view != null) {
                view.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED);
            }
            listener.onItemClick(this, view, mPinnedSection.position, mPinnedSection.id);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isItemViewTypePinned(ListAdapter adapter, int viewType) {
        if (adapter instanceof HeaderViewListAdapter) {
            adapter = ((HeaderViewListAdapter)adapter).getWrappedAdapter();
        }
        return ((PinnedSectionListAdapter) adapter).isItemViewTypePinned(viewType);
    }

}
```

[image]

For second time get me error here :

```
SimpleAdapter adapt = new SimpleAdapter(_context, result, resultT, count, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1);
        setListAdapter(adapt);
```

Comment: post your `logcat ` error log

Comment: @e4c5 . Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the last bit of code from line 202 of PinnedSectionListView.java ?

Comment: Yes I know but how I can resolve this problem? problem is here :if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
            {
                PinnedSectionListActivity xx = new PinnedSectionListActivity();
                xx.flag = false;
                xx.test();
            }

Comment: What is test() doing ? Can you please share code of test()

Comment: I will email my cod for you now. thanks

Comment: @Haresh Chhanelana . The Size of project is more than 25MB . How I can send it for you ?

Comment: @Haresh Chhanelana . I am using a Library https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview . I succeed show my data in this List . But book have a lot of rows and when I load activity it toke 13 seconds .And I am fetching data from Sqlite "LIMIT 10" for to increase rate speed now but get me crash.
test() : and when list arrive to Latest Item I need to get next 10 rows and append then to listView but crash me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not using PinnedSectionListActivity current reference properly,If you wan to access your current public function inside any other class then you have to pass your current activity reference :

**Declaration**

private Context context;

**Get current activity reference**

```
public PinnedSectionListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
     super(context, attrs);
     this.context = context;
     initView();
}

public PinnedSectionListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
     super(context, attrs, defStyle);
     this.context = context;
     initView();
}
```

Use current activity reference in onScroll() :

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

     if (mDelegateOnScrollListener != null) { // delegate
          mDelegateOnScrollListener.onScroll(view, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
     }

     if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
     {
         if(context!=null){
            ((PinnedSectionListActivity)context).cleans();
         }
     }else {
            // get expected adapter or fail fast
            ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
            if (adapter == null || visibleItemCount == 0) return; // nothing to do

                final boolean isFirstVisibleItemSection = isItemViewTypePinned(adapter, adapter.getItemViewType(firstVisibleItem));

                if (isFirstVisibleItemSection) {
                    View sectionView = getChildAt(0);
                    if (sectionView.getTop() == getPaddingTop()) { // view sticks to the top, no need for pinned shadow
                        destroyPinnedShadow();
                    } else { // section doesn't stick to the top, make sure we have a pinned shadow
                        ensureShadowForPosition(firstVisibleItem, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount);
                    }

                } else { // section is not at the first visible position
                    int sectionPosition = findCurrentSectionPosition(firstVisibleItem);
                    if (sectionPosition > -1) { // we have section position
                        ensureShadowForPosition(sectionPosition, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount);
                    } else { // there is no section for the first visible item, destroy shadow
                        destroyPinnedShadow();
                    }
                }
    }
};
```

PinnedSectionListView full activity code :

```
public class PinnedSectionListView extends ListView {

    //-- inner classes

    /** List adapter to be implemented for being used with PinnedSectionListView adapter. */
    public static interface PinnedSectionListAdapter extends ListAdapter {
        /** This method shall return 'true' if views of given type has to be pinned. */
        boolean isItemViewTypePinned(int viewType);
    }

    /** Wrapper class for pinned section view and its position in the list. */
    static class PinnedSection {
        public View view;
        public int position;
        public long id;
    }

    //-- class fields

    // fields used for handling touch events
    private final Rect mTouchRect = new Rect();
    private final PointF mTouchPoint = new PointF();
    private int mTouchSlop;
    private View mTouchTarget;
    private MotionEvent mDownEvent;

    // fields used for drawing shadow under a pinned section
    private GradientDrawable mShadowDrawable;
    private int mSectionsDistanceY;
    private int mShadowHeight;

    /** Delegating listener, can be null. */
    OnScrollListener mDelegateOnScrollListener;

    /** Shadow for being recycled, can be null. */
    PinnedSection mRecycleSection;

    /** shadow instance with a pinned view, can be null. */
    PinnedSection mPinnedSection;

    /** Pinned view Y-translation. We use it to stick pinned view to the next section. */
    int mTranslateY;
    private Context context;

    /** Scroll listener which does the magic */
    private final OnScrollListener mOnScrollListener = new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (mDelegateOnScrollListener != null) { // delegate
                mDelegateOnScrollListener.onScrollStateChanged(view, scrollState);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if (mDelegateOnScrollListener != null) { // delegate
                mDelegateOnScrollListener.onScroll(view, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
            }
            if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
            {
                if(context!=null){
                    ((PinnedSectionListActivity)context).cleans();
                }
            }else {
                // get expected adapter or fail fast
                ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
                if (adapter == null || visibleItemCount == 0) return; // nothing to do

                final boolean isFirstVisibleItemSection = isItemViewTypePinned(adapter, adapter.getItemViewType(firstVisibleItem));

                if (isFirstVisibleItemSection) {
                    View sectionView = getChildAt(0);
                    if (sectionView.getTop() == getPaddingTop()) { // view sticks to the top, no need for pinned shadow
                        destroyPinnedShadow();
                    } else { // section doesn't stick to the top, make sure we have a pinned shadow
                        ensureShadowForPosition(firstVisibleItem, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount);
                    }

                } else { // section is not at the first visible position
                    int sectionPosition = findCurrentSectionPosition(firstVisibleItem);
                    if (sectionPosition > -1) { // we have section position
                        ensureShadowForPosition(sectionPosition, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount);
                    } else { // there is no section for the first visible item, destroy shadow
                        destroyPinnedShadow();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

    };

    /** Default change observer. */
    private final DataSetObserver mDataSetObserver = new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override public void onChanged() {
            recreatePinnedShadow();
        };
        @Override public void onInvalidated() {
            recreatePinnedShadow();
        }
    };

    //-- constructors

    public PinnedSectionListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        initView();
    }

    public PinnedSectionListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        setOnScrollListener(mOnScrollListener);
        mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext()).getScaledTouchSlop();
        initShadow(true);
    }

    //-- public API methods

    public void setShadowVisible(boolean visible) {
        initShadow(visible);
        if (mPinnedSection != null) {
            View v = mPinnedSection.view;
            invalidate(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom() + mShadowHeight);
        }
    }

    //-- pinned section drawing methods

    public void initShadow(boolean visible) {
        if (visible) {
            if (mShadowDrawable == null) {
                mShadowDrawable = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                        new int[] { Color.parseColor("#ffa0a0a0"), Color.parseColor("#50a0a0a0"), Color.parseColor("#00a0a0a0")});
                mShadowHeight = (int) (8 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            }
        } else {
            if (mShadowDrawable != null) {
                mShadowDrawable = null;
                mShadowHeight = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /** Create shadow wrapper with a pinned view for a view at given position */
    void createPinnedShadow(int position) {

        // try to recycle shadow
        PinnedSection pinnedShadow = mRecycleSection;
        mRecycleSection = null;

        // create new shadow, if needed
        if (pinnedShadow == null) pinnedShadow = new PinnedSection();
        // request new view using recycled view, if such
        View pinnedView = getAdapter().getView(position, pinnedShadow.view, PinnedSectionListView.this);

        // read layout parameters
        LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) pinnedView.getLayoutParams();
        if (layoutParams == null) {
            layoutParams = (LayoutParams) generateDefaultLayoutParams();
            pinnedView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }

        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(layoutParams.height);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(layoutParams.height);

        if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) heightMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;

        int maxHeight = getHeight() - getListPaddingTop() - getListPaddingBottom();
        if (heightSize > maxHeight) heightSize = maxHeight;

        // measure & layout
        int ws = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth() - getListPaddingLeft() - getListPaddingRight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int hs = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(heightSize, heightMode);
        pinnedView.measure(ws, hs);
        pinnedView.layout(0, 0, pinnedView.getMeasuredWidth(), pinnedView.getMeasuredHeight());
        mTranslateY = 0;

        // initialize pinned shadow
        pinnedShadow.view = pinnedView;
        pinnedShadow.position = position;
        pinnedShadow.id = getAdapter().getItemId(position);

        // store pinned shadow
        mPinnedSection = pinnedShadow;
    }

    /** Destroy shadow wrapper for currently pinned view */
    void destroyPinnedShadow() {
        if (mPinnedSection != null) {
            // keep shadow for being recycled later
            mRecycleSection = mPinnedSection;
            mPinnedSection = null;
        }
    }

    /** Makes sure we have an actual pinned shadow for given position. */
    void ensureShadowForPosition(int sectionPosition, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount) {
        if (visibleItemCount < 2) { // no need for creating shadow at all, we have a single visible item
            destroyPinnedShadow();
            return;
        }

        if (mPinnedSection != null
                && mPinnedSection.position != sectionPosition) { // invalidate shadow, if required
            destroyPinnedShadow();
        }

        if (mPinnedSection == null) { // create shadow, if empty
            createPinnedShadow(sectionPosition);
        }

        // align shadow according to next section position, if needed
        int nextPosition = sectionPosition + 1;
        if (nextPosition < getCount()) {
            int nextSectionPosition = findFirstVisibleSectionPosition(nextPosition,
                    visibleItemCount - (nextPosition - firstVisibleItem));
            if (nextSectionPosition > -1) {
                View nextSectionView = getChildAt(nextSectionPosition - firstVisibleItem);
                final int bottom = mPinnedSection.view.getBottom() + getPaddingTop();
                mSectionsDistanceY = nextSectionView.getTop() - bottom;
                if (mSectionsDistanceY < 0) {
                    // next section overlaps pinned shadow, move it up
                    mTranslateY = mSectionsDistanceY;
                } else {
                    // next section does not overlap with pinned, stick to top
                    mTranslateY = 0;
                }
            } else {
                // no other sections are visible, stick to top
                mTranslateY = 0;
                mSectionsDistanceY = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
        }

    }

    int findFirstVisibleSectionPosition(int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount) {
        ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();

        int adapterDataCount = adapter.getCount();
        if (getLastVisiblePosition() >= adapterDataCount) return -1; // dataset has changed, no candidate

        if (firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount >= adapterDataCount){//added to prevent index Outofbound (in case)
            visibleItemCount = adapterDataCount-firstVisibleItem;
        }

        for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < visibleItemCount; childIndex++) {
            int position = firstVisibleItem + childIndex;
            int viewType = adapter.getItemViewType(position);
            if (isItemViewTypePinned(adapter, viewType)) return position;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    int findCurrentSectionPosition(int fromPosition) {
        ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();

        if (fromPosition >= adapter.getCount()) return -1; // dataset has changed, no candidate

        if (adapter instanceof SectionIndexer) {
            // try fast way by asking section indexer
            SectionIndexer indexer = (SectionIndexer) adapter;
            int sectionPosition = indexer.getSectionForPosition(fromPosition);
            int itemPosition = indexer.getPositionForSection(sectionPosition);
            int typeView = adapter.getItemViewType(itemPosition);
            if (isItemViewTypePinned(adapter, typeView)) {
                return itemPosition;
            } // else, no luck
        }

        // try slow way by looking through to the next section item above
        for (int position=fromPosition; position>=0; position--) {
            int viewType = adapter.getItemViewType(position);
            if (isItemViewTypePinned(adapter, viewType)) return position;
        }
        return -1; // no candidate found
    }

    void recreatePinnedShadow() {
        destroyPinnedShadow();
        ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
        if (adapter != null && adapter.getCount() > 0) {
            int firstVisiblePosition = getFirstVisiblePosition();
            int sectionPosition = findCurrentSectionPosition(firstVisiblePosition);
            if (sectionPosition == -1) return; // no views to pin, exit
            ensureShadowForPosition(sectionPosition,
                    firstVisiblePosition, getLastVisiblePosition() - firstVisiblePosition);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener listener) {
        if (listener == mOnScrollListener) {
            super.setOnScrollListener(listener);
        } else {
            mDelegateOnScrollListener = listener;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        post(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() { // restore pinned view after configuration change
                recreatePinnedShadow();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {

        // assert adapter in debug mode
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && adapter != null) {
            if (!(adapter instanceof PinnedSectionListAdapter))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Does your adapter implement PinnedSectionListAdapter?");
            if (adapter.getViewTypeCount() < 2)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Does your adapter handle at least two types" +
                        " of views in getViewTypeCount() method: items and sections?");
        }

        // unregister observer at old adapter and register on new one
        ListAdapter oldAdapter = getAdapter();
        if (oldAdapter != null) oldAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        if (adapter != null) adapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);

        // destroy pinned shadow, if new adapter is not same as old one
        if (oldAdapter != adapter) destroyPinnedShadow();

        super.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        if (mPinnedSection != null) {
            int parentWidth = r - l - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
            int shadowWidth = mPinnedSection.view.getWidth();
            if (parentWidth != shadowWidth) {
                recreatePinnedShadow();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        if (mPinnedSection != null) {

            // prepare variables
            int pLeft = getListPaddingLeft();
            int pTop = getListPaddingTop();
            View view = mPinnedSection.view;

            // draw child
            canvas.save();

            int clipHeight = view.getHeight() +
                    (mShadowDrawable == null ? 0 : Math.min(mShadowHeight, mSectionsDistanceY));
            canvas.clipRect(pLeft, pTop, pLeft + view.getWidth(), pTop + clipHeight);

            canvas.translate(pLeft, pTop + mTranslateY);
            drawChild(canvas, mPinnedSection.view, getDrawingTime());

            if (mShadowDrawable != null && mSectionsDistanceY > 0) {
                mShadowDrawable.setBounds(mPinnedSection.view.getLeft(),
                        mPinnedSection.view.getBottom(),
                        mPinnedSection.view.getRight(),
                        mPinnedSection.view.getBottom() + mShadowHeight);
                mShadowDrawable.draw(canvas);
            }

            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

    //-- touch handling methods

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();
        final int action = ev.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                && mTouchTarget == null
                && mPinnedSection != null
                && isPinnedViewTouched(mPinnedSection.view, x, y)) { // create touch target

            // user touched pinned view
            mTouchTarget = mPinnedSection.view;
            mTouchPoint.x = x;
            mTouchPoint.y = y;

            // copy down event for eventually be used later
            mDownEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
        }

        if (mTouchTarget != null) {
            if (isPinnedViewTouched(mTouchTarget, x, y)) { // forward event to pinned view
                mTouchTarget.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            }

            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) { // perform onClick on pinned view
                super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
                performPinnedItemClick();
                clearTouchTarget();

            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) { // cancel
                clearTouchTarget();

            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                if (Math.abs(y - mTouchPoint.y) > mTouchSlop) {

                    // cancel sequence on touch target
                    MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
                    event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                    mTouchTarget.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                    event.recycle();

                    // provide correct sequence to super class for further handling
                    super.dispatchTouchEvent(mDownEvent);
                    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
                    clearTouchTarget();

                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        // call super if this was not our pinned view
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private boolean isPinnedViewTouched(View view, float x, float y) {
        view.getHitRect(mTouchRect);

        // by taping top or bottom padding, the list performs on click on a border item.
        // we don't add top padding here to keep behavior consistent.
        mTouchRect.top += mTranslateY;

        mTouchRect.bottom += mTranslateY + getPaddingTop();
        mTouchRect.left += getPaddingLeft();
        mTouchRect.right -= getPaddingRight();
        return mTouchRect.contains((int)x, (int)y);
    }

    private void clearTouchTarget() {
        mTouchTarget = null;
        if (mDownEvent != null) {
            mDownEvent.recycle();
            mDownEvent = null;
        }
    }

    private boolean performPinnedItemClick() {
        if (mPinnedSection == null) return false;

        OnItemClickListener listener = getOnItemClickListener();
        if (listener != null && getAdapter().isEnabled(mPinnedSection.position)) {
            View view =  mPinnedSection.view;
            playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
            if (view != null) {
                view.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED);
            }
            listener.onItemClick(this, view, mPinnedSection.position, mPinnedSection.id);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isItemViewTypePinned(ListAdapter adapter, int viewType) {
        if (adapter instanceof HeaderViewListAdapter) {
            adapter = ((HeaderViewListAdapter)adapter).getWrappedAdapter();
        }
        return ((PinnedSectionListAdapter) adapter).isItemViewTypePinned(viewType);
    }

}
```

Comment: @ Haresh Chhelana .Thanks a lot . I send for you an email . ;)